# how to import and create index using json file

Tags: json, ubuntu, curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a index by using a json file. I am using Elasticsearch and Kibana 5.4.1 and Ubuntu 16.04. And I am trying with below mentioned command.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/plants/plants_type/1' --data-binary @plants_json.json
```

But I am getting below mentioned error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}},"status":400}
```

I have tried to find the answer by using "stackoverflow" & other sources. But did not find any solution. I am new in Elasticsearch. So I am facing difficulties to correct it. It would be really great if someone help me to find the correct command to create a index by using a json file (for 5.4.1 elasticsearch version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `Content-Type` header to your request. By default it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you need to change it to `application\json`. So your command should look like this

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/plants/plants_type/1' -d @plants_json.json
```

Comment: @ Ruben Vardanyan: I have changed the command as per your instruction but still getting an error. I have updated the the error message as per new one. Can you help me further to solve/find out the problem?

Comment: I have identified the problem. The problem is with the format of json file. I have updated it and make it readable by elasticsearch. Problem has been solved. And thanks for you help regarding the content type.